# yii - how to theming widgets in modules

Tags: php, yii

I have directory structure like:

```
   .
   |-config
   |-modules
   |---articles
   |---catalog
   |-----components
   |-----controllers
   |-----fixtures
   |-----migrations
   |-----models
   |-----views
   |-----widgets <----------------- MY WIDGETS
   |------ FooWidget.php
   |-------views
   |--------- foo.php <--- default view, not working
   |-runtime
   |-tests
   |-themes
   |---XXXX
   |-----assets
   |-----views
   |-------catalog <--------------- MODULE VIEWS
   |-------layouts
   |-------widgets
   |-views
   |-widgets
```

I call $this->widget('application.modules.catalog.widgets.FooWidget') - and catch exception CException - view not found.
How to theming widgets inside modules?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWidget#viewPath-detail)
your widget views should be in `/themes/XXXX/views/FooWidget/foo.php`.